# Link to a section on horizontal web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

A short introduction is, I have created a website where I have 3 divs positioned horizontally on mobile devices (see image below), done with help from Bootstrap's carousel and a swipe function added on top from **avinoamr's** repo: https://github.com/avinoamr/bootstrap-carousel-swipe

[image: bootstrap with swipe]

Problem now is that I'm trying to add function by clicking the "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" buttons on top-menu to get to the respective divs on the same page by using the href #:

```
<li class="col-sm-4"> <a href="#tab2">Tab2</a> </li>
```

...with divs like this one:

```
<div id="tab2" class="item active">
    <div class="col-sm-12 yellow" id="yellow">
    </div>
  </div>
```

...but for some reason it doesn't trigger the jump. Any idea?

You can see the original syntax here:
https://jsfiddle.net/wmvx1p9t/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using the `id` attribute will not automatically trigger the Bootstrap carousel to change position.
The [carousel documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) defines two ways you can trigger the carousel to scroll:

- [Via data attributes](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-data-attributes-4): By adding the `data-slide` attribute to your tab anchors. Your tab anchors will have to be inside the carousel `<div>` for it to work.
- [Via JavaScript](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript-4): You can attach a click event listener to the tab anchors and manually trigger the carousel to cycle to the corresponding item by using: `$('.carousel').carousel(number)`

Comment: The event listeners worked perfectly! 
I added: 
" onclick="swipeFunction(0)" " on the tabs and: 
" function swipeFunction(index) {
  $('.carousel').carousel(index);
} " in jQuery :)

Comment: Now I encountered the opposite problem (I hate myself for being noob) and can't get it to work. For those who are interested, please have a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567531/make-current-div-change-relevant-menu-tab-to-active