# Make current div change relevant menu tab to active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my mobile project I can press a menu tab (Tab2) and the tab becomes active (with background color for the active class) and the corresponding div (Div2) below will appear on the screen. 
If I press another tab, that tab gets active with corr. div etc...all in all, works perfect!

But now I have the opposite problem, I want to press (in my case, swipe) a div onto my screen and have the corresponding tab above to be active (with color). e.g. swipe in Div1 on screen, Tab1 should be active and have a certain background color. Swipe in Div2, then Tab2 should be active instead etc. but can't get it to work.

Below are my li tags:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills mobileNavbar">
  <li onclick="swipeFunction(0)" class="col-xs-4 tab1" data-index="0"><a href="#">STREAM</a></li>
  <li onclick="swipeFunction(1)" class="col-xs-4 tab2" data-index="1"><a href="#">CHAT</a></li>
  <li onclick="swipeFunction(2)" class="col-xs-4 tab3" data-index="2"><a href="#">IDE</a></li>
</ul>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {

  var savedIndex = $(this).find('.active').index();

  if (savedIndex === 0){
    // I want Tab1 to be active here
  } else if (savedIndex == 1){
    // I want Tab2 to be active here
  } else if (savedIndex == 2){
    // I want Tab3 to be active here
  }
});
```

For more details into what I'm trying to build, incl. libs, images (and my previous problem, solved by "Pieter"):

[Link to a section on horizontal web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37546342/link-to-a-section-on-horizontal-web-page)

Comment: You have written the same in thing in all the conditions...?

Answer (score 2):

As I commented above, you are doing same thing in all the conditions. All you need to do is, to **activate the navigation item by index you are getting from carousel**. Try this:

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {

    var savedIndex = $(this).find('.active').index();

    $('.nav-pills>li:eq(' + savedIndex + ')>a').css('background', 'yellow');
});
```

**EDIT:**

I would recommend to play with a CSS class instead of inline css. Try this:

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {

    var savedIndex = $(this).find('.active').index();

    $('.nav-pills>li:eq(' + savedIndex + ')>a')
        .addClass("active") // add active class to the current one
        .parent().siblings() // select sibling navigation items
        .removeClass("active"); // remove active class from the other navigations
});
```

Comment: You might want to reset other `css`

Comment: Though is i one-liner, but invoking many methods will somehow reduce the performance. I would have opted for `$('.nav-pills>li').removeClass('...')`.. As _3-4_ in real-time scenario, length of items could be more than shared in OP..

Comment: @Rayon operating on 3-4 items would hardly impact the performance. But I agree with that. :)

Comment: @Ashish...you sir are a genius! I would never have guessed that myself! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are most welcome mate... I am glad I could help. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You conveniently already have classnames "tab1", "tab2", "tab3" on the tabs, which can be matched easily based on `savedIndex`:

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
  $('.nav li').removeClass('active'); // clear the old one
  var savedIndex = $(this).find('.active').index();
  $('.tab'+ (savedIndex+1)).addClass('active'); // add the new one
});
```

(I believe `index()` returns an integer, but if not you may need to `parseInt` it before adding 1.)